# When I start Windows Explorer it restarts or stops working. Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Often, when opening Windows Explorer, I encounter the following error and Windows Explorer needs to restart:
[image: restart process]
[image: error process]

Here I am using Windows 7 with an Intel Core 2 Duo processor and 2GB of RAM, is this caused by a virus or other causes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be caused by many things. This happens to me a lot when recovering from being taken over by RDP. It doesn't necessarily mean you have a virus but It's likely 3rd party code causing the crash. (Something registered in your shell).

Fortunately explorer's become fairly resillient in windows vista/7 to crashes.

What I suggest is you use [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to selectively disable shell extensions you don't need and see if the problem goes away.

If you're up to it you can to a systematic approach to pinpoint if any extension is causing this. Should you have no luck here you could have a number of problems but with out more information it's going to be difficult to diagnose.

Comment: How if this happens when plugging in USB flash drive ?

Comment: @TOFIK: Pardon me? I'm not quite sure I understand your question.

Comment: i ever plugging in USB flash drive to my laptop and and found the problem like that (windows explorer error) what caused it to happen ?

Comment: You're noticing this is happening when you plug your USB Key into your computer? If so, that could be an infected USB Key or a bad driver.

Comment: Ok it make me understand ...